# Swift 2.0 Wcf Restful Service Consuming

Tags: ios, wcf, rest, swift2

I want to consume a restful wcf service in swift. I found sth. about it but didn't work. There is the code Can anybody say what is wrong with it.(I have a label and a button i want click the button and show result in label.)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var lblGetMsg: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func btnGetMsg(sender: AnyObject) {

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://ip.jsontest.com")

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
            print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
            self.lblGetMsg.text=(String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        }

        task.resume()

    }
}
```

Comment: `but didn't work` What does that mean? I tried your code and it worked, the data is retrieved, it is `{"ip": "82.241.126.9"}`. Now all you have to do is deserialize the JSON string and grab the content, then put it on your label.

Comment: Thanks for your answers i am get errors like:
 btnGetMsg:forEvent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155540ef0
2016-01-19 11:53:55.476 wcfTest[332:77449] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[wcfTest.ViewController btnGetMsg:forEvent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155540ef0'
*** First throw call stack:
...
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

i am getting these because did not serialized ?